# how to solve factorial involving multiplication

Tags: arithmetic, factorial

I am trying to solve this question but not able to find any helpful material. It involves factorial with multiplications,

$$\frac{8!}{5!}\cdot \frac{7!}{7!10!}$$

I tried crossing 8 and 5 and 7 with 7 but it's not giving me right answer

Comment: What question? Do you mean, you are trying to evaluate that expression as a number? Do you know what "8!" stands for?

Comment: Is it $\frac{7!}{(7!)(10!)}$ or $\frac{7!}{7!}10!$

Comment: @AntonioVargas it's first one :)

Comment: Could you show your steps in detail?

Comment: Hint: $10! = 10\times9\times8!$

Comment: @RahulNarain thanks for hint, but seems like it lead me to wrong answer, answer is 7/15, whereas I am getting 7/a large number in thousands...  Can someone pass me link to any similar solved problem please

Comment: @MuhammadRaja: Please show the steps that lead you to think the value of your expression is 7/15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac{8!}{5!}\cdot \dfrac{7!}{7!10!}=\dfrac{8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}\cdot\dfrac{7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot10!}\\=8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot\dfrac{1}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}\\=\dfrac{8\cdot7\cdot6}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}=\dfrac{1}{10\cdot9\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}\\=\dfrac{1}{10800}$.

You can also think of it like the following:

$\dfrac{8!}{5!}\cdot \dfrac{7!}{7!10!}=\dfrac{8\cdot7!}{5!}\cdot\dfrac{7\cdot6\cdot5!}{7!10!}\\=\dfrac{8\cdot7\cdot6}{10!}=\dfrac{8\cdot7\cdot6}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}\\=\dfrac{1}{10\cdot9\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}\\=\dfrac{1}{10800}$

Comment: +1 I feel this answer is of more appropriate detail for the given question, but I think @Waytoinfinity showed the most natural way to answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{8!}{5!}\cdot \dfrac{7!}{7!10!} = \dfrac{8!}{5!\cdot 8! \cdot 9\cdot10} 
                                       = \dfrac{1}{120 \cdot90} = \dfrac{1}{10800}  $.

Answer (score 2):

my steps:
$ \dfrac{8!}{5!}\cdot\dfrac{7!}{7!\cdot10!} $
7! and 7! cancel out: $\dfrac{8!}{5!} \cdot \dfrac{1}{10!}$

next:
$ \dfrac{8!}{5!} \cdot \dfrac{1}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8!} $
Here, 8! cross-cancel : $\dfrac{1}{5!} \cdot \dfrac{1}{10 \cdot 9} $

next:
$ \dfrac{1}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 5!}$

which is $\dfrac{1}{ 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 5 \cdot4 \cdot3 \cdot2\cdot1}$ which ended up being $ 9.26 * 10^{-5} $
or $\dfrac{1}{10800}$

Comment: Please edit your previous answer if you've made a mistake, rather than making a new answer.

Comment: You should read the rules of this site very carefully . Please edit your previous answer .

Comment: @Waytoinfinity very sorry, i'm very new to this site. i joined about an hour ago. i'll read the rules now